# Wordpress VS RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, wordpress

I have two solutions to program a site: Wordpress and RoR. First is easier to deploy (which is important since some people will have to work to install passenger, rvm and configure git if I chose rails) but I suspect Wordpress to be really slower in terms of performance than RoR.

The site will be full of AJAX requests and I'd prefer to use the solution which is the best in terms of performance. But, I'm not totally sure if the difference is big enough or not.

What do you think? Do you know if my feeling is true/false about the slowness of `WordPress` compared to rails performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a lot of experience with **Ruby on Rails**, but I do with **WordPress**. In this scenario, I would go with the application that best suits your needs in terms of feature-set and ease of use. **WordPress** powers some of the top sites on the web: [Smashing Magazine](http://smashingmagazine.com), [Tech Crunch](http://techcrunch.com), [CNN's news blogs](http://news.blogs.cnn.com/), and plenty more. The bottom line is regardless of any speed comparison, with the proper setup, you can achieve enterprise level performance with **WordPress**.

Which CMS are you referring to for Ruby on Rails? You're asking for a comparison between a piece of software and a language/platform. ;)

**Edit:**

As an example of awesome performance at huge scale for Ruby on Rails, [GitHub](http://github.com) uses it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the documented answer, I will go with Wordpress this time, you put me in the right way. Actually, in this project, setting up the whole thing with custom post types or from scaffolding asks for the same amount of time (more or less).

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing two different things. Wordpress is a CMS. Ruby on Rails is a framework. You can install a wordpress in minutes, but has less flexibility than with a framework.

If you want flexibility and scalability you need to use a framework like Ruby on Rails, symphony, django ... etc

Regards!

Comment: Actually, I can do exactly the same with both and with ease. But Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Caching is going to be the answer for you regardless of whether you use RoR or WP.

As it has been mentioned in other answers, RoR is a framework which means you will either have to build your own CMS or install a vendor package. This means your question is more about that answer than RoR.

We power some pretty big sites with WP and as it scales, you don't have a choice but to cache.

I'd personally be more worried about the user experience for your users (both visitors and administrators) than speed as site speed should be measured in milliseconds, training is measured in minutes or hours.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I will look more into cache. For user experience, a good admin with active admin or the admin of wordpress with custom post types are pretty the same for administrators. For users, there won't be any difference.